# Is the PHP include an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, include, request

I recently read an article about why you shouldn't use too many HTTP request, cause it will slow down your server. Which seems to be true, at least with JavaScript AJAX HTTP requests. But what about the PHP include? Will there be a difference in the server performance if I send 4 AJAX request compared to if I send 1 AJAX request to a page which then does 4 PHP include fetches.

Here's an image of the scenario I'm trying to explain:

[image: Ajax vs. PHP include]

Comment: [No, an include isn't an http request](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is **NO** PHP includes are not HTTP requests and are being processed by PHP interpreter during script execution.

However there is something called *include through HTTP*, which is specific scenario where you include file using HTTP protocol.

You can read this link from PHP manual for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 2):

Includes happen on the server when the script is executed, there are no http requests involved in that process. These are two totally separate and different things.
Optimize the number of http (ajax) requests and do not worry about includes in that context. I'm not even sure how you could substitute one for another. Includes are basically a way to structure your program into logical chunks to enable better maintainability and reusability. Http requests are the method used to communicate between the client (browser) and your program (server).