# CDN link is not working using PHP include

Tags: php, include

I'm using PHP include this is working fine on my local but when I using include file as CDN like given below then it is not working. I don't know what is wrong with it.

This is working:

```html
<?php include 'include/head.php' ?>
```

This is not working:

```html
<?php include 'http://example.com/cdn/include/head.php' ?>
```

I need to use include as CDN because I have multiple directories and pages so I can't manage with the working example as given above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the PHP include an HTTP request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058078/is-the-php-include-an-http-request)

Comment: CDNs are normally for CSS and JavaScript, not PHP. Also it's unclear why multiple directories means you can't use include...but it's true that you might be better with an autoloader. Your scenario here seems, on the face of it, not to be the usual use case for a CDN

Answer (score 1):

CDN is for using JS and CSS files, not to include in your system. If you want to do that, just download and reference it from your directory.
The purpose for CDN is to have the proper file loaded from the closest (most likely the fastest) place served.

ALSO: including from an URL is only an option if you have the allow_url_include PHP.ini variable set to 1/on.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include

For security reasons I won't do that and that's why it is disabled by PHP default